# Not able to create new feature in feature layer

Tags: arcgis-enterprise

I am using a ArcGIS Enterprise (server+portal) 10.9.1. I have a feature layer which needs to be edited. I can edit the existing geometry but when I  try to create a new geometry 2 attributes are coming as blank which in return is not allowing me to create the geometry.

[image]

Any idea why it's working in this way. The same data works fine with a standalone server. Problem is coming when I use federated server.

Comment: Does your feature class have a Z or M geometry type? If so it will refuse to store features that don't have a valid Z (height) or M (measure), if your application is creating 2d lines they will not store in a ZM enabled feature class, it sould give the error *coordinates or measures out of bounds*.